# Copy file to multiple folders with specific foldername (batch file)

Tags: batch-file

I have sub folder like : `c:\main\bot01\sb0102` -> `sb0199` , `c:\main\bot99\sb9901` -> `sb9999`.

How can I make a batch file to copy 1 file to every folder start with "sb" ?
as there is many "*sb*" folders, I cant make command for every line of them like this:

```
xcopy "C:\test.txt" "c:\main\bot01\sb0102" /y
```

Comment: Try this `@For /D %%A In ("C:\main\bot01\sb*") Do @Copy /Y "C:\test.txt" "%%A"`!

Comment: Is this meant to repeat the bot number in the first two digits of sb number? And why do you start with sb0102 instead of sb0101?

Comment: my mistake, its should be sb0101 to sb0199 for bot01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two nested counting `for /l` loops,

- the first running from 101 to 199 to maintain a leading zero.
- and using substrings to get only the last 2/4 digits what requires delayed expansion.

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\06\SO_54064719.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Sourcefile=C:\test.txt"
for /l %%B in (101,1,199) do (
    set bot=%%B
    Echo ---- bot !bot:~-2! ----
    for /l %%S in (1,1,99) do (
        Set /A sb=bot*100+%%S
        echo Copy /B /Y "%Sourcefile%" "C:\main\bot!bot:~-2!\sb!sb:~-4!"
    )
)
```

---

```
> Q:\Test\2019\01\06\SO_54064719.cmd
---- bot 01 ----
Copy /B /Y "C:\test.txt" "C:\main\bot01\sb0101"
Copy /B /Y "C:\test.txt" "C:\main\bot01\sb0102"
...
Copy /B /Y "C:\test.txt" "C:\main\bot01\sb0198"
Copy /B /Y "C:\test.txt" "C:\main\bot01\sb0199"
---- bot 02 ----
Copy /B /Y "C:\test.txt" "C:\main\bot02\sb0201"
Copy /B /Y "C:\test.txt" "C:\main\bot02\sb0202"
...
```

If the output looks OK, remove the echo in front of copy.

Just to show a powershell solution which allows a range in several levels

```
Get-ChildItem C:\main\bot[0-9][0-9]\sb[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] -Dir|ForEach-Object{
    Copy-Item C:\test.txt -Destination $_
}
```

To be on topic wrapped in cmdline/batch

```
powershell -NoP -C "Get-ChildItem C:\main\bot[0-9][0-9]\sb[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] -Dir|ForEach-Object{Copy-Item C:\test.txt -Destination $_}"
```

Comment: A deserved +1, for going the extra mile and doing the entire task for them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my comment as an answer

From a batch file:

```bat
@For /D %%A In ("C:\main\bot01\sb*") Do @Copy /Y "C:\test.txt" "%%A" >Nul 2>&1
```

From the Command Prompt:

```bat
For /D %A In ("C:\main\bot01\sb*") Do @Copy /Y "C:\test.txt" "%A" >Nul 2>&1
```